# wx.Sound : wav file unsupported

Tags: audio, background, wxpython, wav

I'm doing a game with `wx.python` and when I try to add a background music using `wx.Sound` I got the following error:

Python error:

> Sound file 'images/game.wav' is in unsupported format.

This is the code I use. I've seen this code many times on the web but none had 
the same problem:

```
sound = wx.Sound("images/game.wav")

sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to save the WAV file in a different format. WAV files are not all created equal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#WAV_file_compression_codecs_compared

Comment: i tested all the samples given on the website but I have now another problem. For the samples 4 and 6 to 15 I still have the problem above but for the 4 other samples (those that finish with PCM) I have no errors but also no sound :(. What can be the problem now? 
And if I use the wav files from other games, it's the same problem... no sound

Comment: What are your OS, Python and wxPython versions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use wx.media or maybe the mplayer widget? I have a tutorial on each of these:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/